# Could I have copy constructor for subclass of QObject?

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor, moc, copy-assignment

[Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator) we can read that no copy construct and copy assignment operator evaluable. But [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) we can read that `qRegisterMetaType` and `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` have to have public default constructor, public copy constructor and public destructor. The question is: who is telling a lie? Or I did not understand it correctly?

Comment: Could you provide any situation, when you need to register `QObject`-based class as metatype? Documentation is OK.

Comment: You don't need to register QObject or its sub classes with qRegisterMetaType.

Comment: `qRegisterMetaType` registers user defined types, not the ones derived from QObject

Comment: @RafalMielniczuk, but why my class must have copy-constructor to work like QObject? I mean storing in QVariant. Any reasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is true:
1. `QObject` can't be copied and all its descendants can't be copied also.
2. `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` accepts objects with public constructor, copy constructor and destructor.

There is no contradiction, because you can't register `QObject` descendants with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`.

EDIT:

When you convert your class to `QVariant` it uses a copy constructor to make a copy of your object:

```
 void *ptr = QMetaType::construct(x->type, copy);
```

Comment: But why my class must have copy-constructor to work like QObject? I mean storing in QVariant.

Comment: Yes, to be stored in `QVariant` your class must have a copy constructor, but it is not "work like QObject", because QObject, QWidget... can't be stored in `QVariant`

Comment: Added explanation about copy constructor to the answer.

Comment: can you also explain me why I cant store QObject in a QVariant?

Comment: The reason is the same that you can't write `QObject o1 = o2`. It doesn't have state, it can't be serialized, deserialized, copied. It's not a kind of storage. `QThread` is also `QObject`. Could you imagine serializing of a thread?)

Comment: So look at `QObject` not as storage but as process, that can't be suspended.

Comment: But what about move semantics? Can I create QVariant from QObject&&?

Comment: No, you can't. But you can create it with a pointer to QObject. However, if you think of copying QObject, I suggest to you consider moving all variables of you object to a `struct` State and then create `QVariant` with this state, then create a new object with the same state.

Answer (score 2):

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro is used to generate information for custom user types, if you want to use them as SIGNAL/SLOT arguments.

Example:

```
struct MyInfo
{
  QString name;
  QDate birthday;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( MyInfo )

// ... somewhere in cpp:
{
  QObject::connect( obj1, SIGNAL( newData( MyInfo ), SLOT( onNewData( MyInfo ) ) );
}
```

Without `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro you could not pass `MyInfo` as signal or slot argument.

If you use cross-thread connections (`Qt::QueuedConnection`, `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`, etc) you also need to register your type with `qRegisterMetatype<MyInfo>();` call.

---

But it is ok, to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` to register POINTERS to QObjects. For example:

```
class MyItem
  : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
//...
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( MyItem * )
// or event better Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( QSharedPointer< MyItem > )
```

Pointers are POD types, that may be constructed, copied, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly implement a copy constructor and assignment operators in a class that derives from `QObject`, but you can't refer to the deleted base class copy constructor and assignment operator. You need to roll your own.

Thus, you need to live with the fact that the copy construction or assignment won't affect the signal/slot connections to either the source or the target object. You must also decide how the parentage is handled when copying - either of the three possible choices are entirely arbitrary - that's why it makes no sense to copy objects in most cases, it's too error prone.

For example, using the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/1329652).

```
class CopyableObject : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  friend void swap(CopyableObject & first, CopyableObject & second) {
    // d_ptr swap doesn't take care of parentage
    QObject * firstParent = first.parent();
    QObject * secondParent = second.parent();
    first.setParent(0);
    second.setParent(0);
    first.d_ptr.swap(second.d_ptr);
    second.setParent(firstParent);
    first.setParent(secondParent);
  }
  CopyableObject(const CopyableObject & other) : QObject(other.parent()) {
    Q_ASSERT(thread() == other.thread());
    setObjectName(other.objectName());
    blockSignals(other.signalsBlocked());
  }
  CopyableObject(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
  // C++11 only
  #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  CopyableObject(CopyableObject && other) : CopyableObject() {
    swap(*this, other);
  }
  #endif
  CopyableObject & operator=(CopyableObject other) {
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Note that you need to reimplement the `swap` function for derived classes.