# Qt creating a class and using in a vector

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I'm new in Qt and C++. I want to implement a vector with using a class called Item. I think I'm doing a beginners mistake. I'm getting the below error. Can someone please help?

C:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.6\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h:631: error: C2280: 'Item::Item(const Item &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Below is my mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QVector>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMessageBox>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}
void MainWindow::AddRoot(QString item)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *itm = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
    itm->setText(0,item);
    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(itm);
}

void MainWindow::AddChild(QTreeWidgetItem *parent,QString item)
{

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    Item item;

    item.setDescription(ui->lineEdit->text());
    data.push_back(item);
    ui->treeWidget->setColumnCount(1);
    AddRoot(item.getDescription());
}
```

And my item.cpp class

```
#include "item.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
Item::Item()
{

}
void Item::setDescription(QString desc)
{
    Description = desc;
}
void Item::setEnterDate(QDateTime enterDate)
{
    EnterDate = enterDate;
}

void Item::setEndDate(QDateTime endDate)
{
    EndDate = endDate;
}

QString Item::getDescription()
{
    return Description;
}

QDateTime Item::getEnterDate()
{
    return EnterDate;
}

QDateTime Item::getEndDate()
{
    return EndDate;
}
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <item.h>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QTreeWidget>
```

mainwindow.h:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QVector<Item> data;
    void AddRoot(QString item);
    void AddChild(QTreeWidgetItem *parent,QString item);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

item.h:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
class Item : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Item(QObject *parent = 0);

    QString Description;
    QDateTime EnterDate;
    QDateTime EndDate;

    QString getDescription();
    QDateTime getEnterDate();
    QDateTime getEndDate();

    void setDescription(QString desc);
    void setEnterDate(QDateTime enterDate);
    void setEndDate(QDateTime endDate);
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

Comment: Can you post the headers as well?

Comment: I've added the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Item` is a `QObject`. `QObject`s are know for not having a copy constructor. In order to use the `QVector`, the item needs to have a copy constructor. Either change `Item` to not being a `QObject`, or use `QSharedPointer` (**but only if you understand ownership**).

Comment: You can of course have a copyable `QObject` subclass, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25890802/1329652).

Comment: @KubaOber That, I did not know. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you both, changing Item to not being QObject has solved my problem.