# Cannot add an instance of a extension of QWidget to a QVector

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I have a class `Variable`, extension of `QWidget`. I want to add it to the vector `QVector <Variable> *list_variables`, but when I try, I get the error

```
Attempt to refer to a deleted function
```

Here is the code :

```
QVector <Variable> *list_variables;
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout (scroll_area);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
{
    Variable *variable = new Variable;
    list_variables->append(*variable); // Error happens here
    layout->addWidget(variable);
}
```

Variable.h :

```
#ifndef VARIABLE_H
#define VARIABLE_H

#include "constant.h"

class Variable : public QWidget
{
    public :
        Variable();

    private :
        QLineEdit *line_edit_name, *line_edit_value, *line_edit_imprecision;
};

#endif // VARIABLE_H
```

Variable.cpp :

```
#include "constant.h"

Variable::Variable()
{
    this->setFixedSize(240, 30);

    line_edit_name = new QLineEdit(this);
    line_edit_name->setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 20);
    line_edit_name->setPlaceholderText("Name");

    line_edit_value = new QLineEdit (this);
    line_edit_value->setGeometry(60, 0, 80, 20);
    line_edit_value->setPlaceholderText("Value");

    line_edit_imprecision = new QLineEdit (this);
    line_edit_imprecision->setGeometry(150, 0, 80, 20);
    line_edit_imprecision->setPlaceholderText("Imprecision");
}
```

All the includes are done in "constant.h"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could I have copy constructor for subclass of QObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890802/could-i-have-copy-constructor-for-subclass-of-qobject)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: declaring the `QVector` as a vector of `Variable` pointers.

So I have:

```
QVector <Variable*> list_variables; // Instead of QVector <Variable> *list_variables;
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout (scroll_area);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
{
    Variable *variable = new Variable;
    list_variables.append(variable); // Instead of list_variables->append(*variable);
    layout->addWidget(variable);
}
```